# Faulty Google Chrome color management with multiple mixed gamut monitors

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, multiple-monitors, color-profiles

I have on my laptop a mixed-gamut three-monitor setup, one HP LP2475W wide-gamut monitor and two HP Z24i 99% sRGB monitors.

When I watch videos that have red areas in them using Google Chrome and a Z24i monitor, some of the red shows as black. Example image of the problem:

[image]

The problem is visible on a screen capture taken using the Print Screen button. So it is not visible just on the display, it is happening within Google Chrome and can be reproduced by Print Screen. Thus, it's a software issue and not a hardware issue.

When I move the problem window to the LP2475W wide-gamut monitor, the black areas disappear.

When I use Firefox instead of Google Chrome, the image looks fine on all displays.

I tested what happens if the Google Chrome window is partially shown on LP2475W and partially on Z24i. Apparently, the problem appears for the entire window if more than half of the window is on Z24i. If more than half of the window is shown on LP2475W, the problem disappears entirely.

I believe this is somehow related to Google Chrome and its color management. I think Google Chrome gets confused if one of the displays is a wide-gamut monitor and the other displays are not.

The operating system is Windows 10. I set the color profile of all displays to be identical sRGB, even for the wide-gamut LP2475W display.

What could the problem be and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hey! I have the exact problem! Here's a working fix: https://superuser.com/posts/comments/2010940?noredirect=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome window changes color depending on which monitor it's open](https://superuser.com/questions/1343273/chrome-window-changes-color-depending-on-which-monitor-its-open)